# Rotating a Relative Layout without using any animation stuff

Tags: android, android-layout, rotation, android-relativelayout

Is there a way to set the duration of rotation without using animation stuff, because those stuff causes some other stuff.

```
relative = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);
relative.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            relative.setRotation(relative.getRotation() + 90);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Just smooth rotation and nothing more!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You literally can't have a smooth rotation without animating it. But, it doesn't have to be difficult. This will rotate your view by an additional 90 degrees over 300 milliseconds, and be nice and smooth:

```
relativeLayout.animate().rotationBy(90).setDuration(300).start();
```

Comment: this is nice but if you rotate a rootview like main container then how to fit it to screen?